# Does the ABS Comm connector just pull off or does it have a special way to fasten?

Tags: ford, abs, taurus, connector, wire

**2004 Ford Taurus SES DOHC 24V**

Trying to pull the wires connector from the ABS control module:

[image]

From what I can see on the replacement, it should just come off:

[image]

However, I am pulling but nothing is budging.

Is there a special way to remove it?

Comment: What vehicle are you dealing with? Year/make/model would be of great assistance.

Comment: There will almost certainly be a latch of some sort holding the connector in place. Likely it will engage the lip that appears to surround the mating connector on the ABS unit. If the new using hasn't been cleaned too carefully you may be able to see where the latch sat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pull (really hard) on this grey lever.

It comes out about 3 inches vertically and unlocks the connector:

[image]

[image]